# Mute audio but make it capturable for screenrecorder in linux

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio, screencasting

I can capture videos with audio for example with simplescreencapture. Usually this just captures what I see on the screen and what I hear from the speakers. If I mute the speakers, no audio is recorded.

However I noticed that on my desktop I can even capture the audio when no external speakers are plugged in (so that I don't have to hear the audio during the capturing).

Now I want to have the same on my laptop. But it doesn't work because of the laptop speakers. I tried to mute just the speaker on alsamixer but then it doesn't capture the audio.

So how can I capture on my laptop videon and audio without hearing the audio while capturing?

I am using lubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Plug in headphones.